# android layout elements going behind bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, xml, mobile, layout

I already searched but I didn't find anything useful for me.

Im developing a simple android app. The problem that I have is that contents in the layout go behind the default bottom navigation bar of a specific mobile phone.

So I have tried two smartphones, in the first the layout was as intended, and it is how it appears [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95DnM.jpg)

In the second smartphone the button is not visible and goes behind the bottom navigation bar (which is not in our code, is the default bar of the smartphone).

After changing the layout to make it fit into the second smartphone, it looks like that in the first one [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GfF8.jpg)

Which is not what I need. 
How do I solve this problem so that I can see the app in every smartphone like the image.1?

This is the fragment.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".profile.Profile_photo_frag">
<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_45sdp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/add_photo"
android:layout_above="@id/add_photo"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:numColumns="2"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
</GridView>
<Button
android:id="@+id/add_photo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gridView"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
android:text="Upload image" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT:
This is the root layout of the tab fragments

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="149dp"
    android:layout_height="141dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_img" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:text="Altro"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="695dp"
    android:text="Nome"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_mail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:text="Mail"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/user_country"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
    android:layout_width="57dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="643dp"
    android:background="#00F3F3F3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/user_country"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/but_p_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/left_border"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_travel" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/but_p_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/left_border"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pictures" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/but_p-posts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/left_border"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_ads" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/left_border"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_commerce" />
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#9C27B0"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/fourth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="509dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey @anonymous, can you post more details about your complete layout. Like how you are using this layout. Since this layout is not showing the upper part of your image.

Comment: @AnujSharma thank you for your answer, I have edited to add what you asked :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem

Comment: Great, can you please upvote/accept my answer. :)

Comment: @AnujSharma I think that is not possible to accept a comment as answer, post an aswer and I'll be happy to do it

Comment: Moved my comment to answer. Thanks 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly its the issue with your view pager height and top margin. You should not set static margin and height rather align the top of your view pager to bottom of your last view in your top view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your constraintLayout add LinearLayout then set your UI, but not used margin to put static value. You can use weight to manage your block. Need some help follow [link](http://Inside%20your%20constraintLayout%20add%20LinearLayout%20then%20set%20your%20UI,%20but%20not%20used%20margin%20to%20put%20static%20value.%20You%20can%20use%20weight%20to%20manage%20your%20block.%20Need%20some%20help%20follow%20link) and more examples available in stack overflow.

I hope it'll help you !